# Selenium - UnreachableBrowserException with IE 9

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting UnreachableBrowserException with Selenium while trying to open a browser through a button click on a UI.

When I execute that method in a stand alone class without the UI the browser opens and the code runs fine. Any suggestions why it might be behaving like tihs

Here is my code

```
    File file = new File("C://IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.ie.driver")); 
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.midomi.com");
```

And the exception stacktrace

```
 Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
 2.39.0.0
 Listening on port 17924  
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session.       Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'
System info: host: 'PC266004', ip: '10.224.236.98', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:225)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:150)
at supervisorycontrol.RecognizeSongHelper.recognizeSong(RecognizeSongHelper.java:32)
at supervisorycontrol.SupervisoryControlView.executeMenuItem(SupervisoryControlView.java:561)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:638)
at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:672)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'
System info: host: 'PC266004', ip: '10.224.236.98', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
... 52 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:17924/status] to be available after 20001 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
... 54 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
... 56 more
```

Comment: you are quite a few versions behind the current IEDriver.. try updating that

Comment: I migrated to 2.42.0.0. Still the same issue

Comment: What is `C://`? Perhaps you meant `C:\\ `?

Comment: It works with that as well on standalone program